# How to solve Talend Job Failing Due to Missing Files

Tags: etl, talend

[image]

the job tbl_IMDbBoxOfficeMojo_Franchises_list_mDB_job_new failed to execute due to missing input files. Specifically, the job was looking for several franchise-related TSV files (e.g., IMDb BoxOfficeMojo - Franchise_ Avengers.tsv), but the system couldn't locate them.

This resulted in the job ending with an exit code of 0, signifying successful termination despite the file I/O failure.

Comment: Sorry but how the F are we to know what you’re supposed to do? Either find the files or don’t. This is not a question we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are using

```
((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")
```

and not

```
((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))
```

in the component `tFileInputDelimited_1` to use the complete path to access the current file.

To abort when there is a problem, check the checkbox *Die On Error* in the `tFileInputDelimited` component.

[image]